# exchange data between Internet Web app (j2ee app) and Android mobile application

Tags: java, android, jakarta-ee

I am working on a Android app prototype, where I need to exchange data between internet Web app and Android mobile application. How can I achieve that, any pointers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One good aproach would be implementing a web-services (RESTful or SOAP, XML or JSON) layer that interacts with the database. Both the webapp and the android app can connect through your WS layer

Answer (score 1):

A good choice is implement a RESTful webservice on the server. To access to it use directly the Apache libraries that comes with Android or you also can use restlet frameworks that work over android like Restlet

Answer (score 1):

As a standard now, you should definitely go with REST Web Service on the server side which will work with data in JSON format. You can find many tutorials on how to create such a service in multiple server containers, JAX-RS implmentations etc. 
You will find a lot of info for reading and writing JSON data to such a service on the Android side as well (any twitter tutorial will do)

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely separate the business and presentation layer using Web Services to expose the business logic.

You could choose to use RESTFul or SOAP web services or any other kind of remote access solution (depending on your resources and requirements), but the key point is to separate your layers.